# Select columns as select statement from other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I want to retrieve some information through a single sql statement through different tables.
I want to do something like:

```
select col1,
       col2,
       (select col1 
          from table 2),
       (select col1 
          from table 3), 
  from table1 
  join table2 
  join table3
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please add table structure, example data and expected output.

Comment: I have three tables as I wrote above, and table1 is related with table2 and table3. Table1 has contains two columns, ex: col3 and col4 that respectively store col1 values of table2 and table3. Actually the tables are big and I don't think it is good to copy them here

Comment: Just a bonus tidbit. If the tables are in a different database you can also use `Database_name`.`Table_Name` to reference the appropriate tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, decide how you want to get the data. If you want to use sub-queries, fine, otherwise use joins. For example, with sub-queries it might look like this:

```
select t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    (select col1 from table2 t2 where t2.field = t1.field),
    (select col1 from table3 t3 where t3.field = t1.field)
from table1 t1
```

In contrast, if you wanted to use joins, it might look like this:

```
select t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    t2.col1,
    t3.col1
from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t2.field = t1.field
    join table3 t3 on t3.field = t1.field
```

Comment: You will probably need at lease t1.col1 in the 2nd statement select list.

Comment: @AlbanoVito - please note!! if you use the first one it will be much slower. MUCH SLOWER.  Unless a smart optimization kicks in it will run the two sub-queries for each row in t1.  Speed is like this: First first query `O(t1N*t2N*t3N)` for second query: `O(t1N)`.  (If indexed correctly on all joining columns)

Comment: @Hogan Thank you very much, but for this case I have to use the first solution, anyway thanks again because in the future I probably will have to use the second one.

Comment: @AlbanoVito - Ok, as you wish.  I'm sad for your server... it has to work so hard!

Answer (score 2):

```
select table1.col1 as t1c1, table1.col2 as t1c2, table2.col1 as t2c1, table3.col1 as t3c1
from table1 
join table2 
join table3
```

note you will need to actually join table2 and table3... join statements like this won't work they don't have the ON part.

Comment: I understand, I just wrote it as an example, Thank you :)